# Refer jQuery .ajax Post to function

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, post

Is it possible to refer an AJAX POST to a specific function within a PHP file?

```
$.ajax({  
     type: "POST",  
     url: "functions.php", //somehow specify function?
     data: "some data...",  
     success: function(){  
          alert('Success!');  
     }  
});
```

Or is there a way to have functions.php receive data and know what to do with it? If not, are there any other suggestions for getting data over to mySQL (using PHP/jQuery)? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data sent to the php file using POST can be accessed in php using:

```
$datasent = $_POST['name'];
```

Given that you sent data as:

```
$.ajax({  
     type: "POST",  
     url: "functions.php", //somehow specify function?
     data: {name:"Jesse"}, //data goes here 
     success: function(){  
          alert('Success!');  
     }  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Not directly. You'd need to post certain data, and have PHP check the POST variables to choose the correct function.

Perhaps [have a look](http://www.google.nl/search?q=php+jquery+ajax+tutorial) at some tutorials (unfotunately the [jQuery links for php tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) are broken).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to refer an AJAX POST to a specific function within a PHP file?

No. jQuery doesn't know what PHP is, even less what a PHP function is. jQuery talks to server side urls. Whether those urls are static html files, PHP scripts, Java servlets, Python I don't know what, CGI scripts, is not really important.

So you could use the data setting to pass parameters to this server side url which based on the values of those parameters could invoke one or another function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a specific function, change ur jquery:

```
 $.ajax({  
     type: "POST",  
     url: "functions.php", //somehow specify function?
     data: {function:"doSomething",name:"Jesse"}, //data goes here 
     success: function(){  
          alert('Success!');  
     }  
});
```

In your php add:

```
call_user_func($_POST['function']); // This will call what ever function name is passed as parameter
function doSomething(){
   echo $_POST['name'];
}
```